# Python - Remove part of a string based on non case sensitive content

Tags: python, string

I'm learning python so I'm not an expert. I have a **string** like the following one (the line break is \n):

```
test1
test2
othertext
test3
test4
```

I would like to remove the *othertext* line but I can't figure out how to do it.
I want this:

```
test1
test2
test3
test4
```

*Othertext* is a text written by hand so I have to consider the possible errors: "OTherTEXT", "other text", "Othe rtext". It's always in one line, so maybe a .strip() could be enough?

Any idea on how can I make this easily?
Should I make a loop that "strips" every part of text between \n and the following \n?

I tried to remove the text with a .replace("othertext", "") but it's a weak implementation.

Comment: You should consider using the difflib module for a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case insensitivity doesn't ignore spaces. So you have to first remove the spaces yourself (with `.replace(" ", "")` then do the comparison. For comparison part, use `.lower()` to convert the text into its lowercase version.

```py
text = """test1
test2
otHeR teXT
test3
test4"""


def remove_line(text: str, word: str) -> str:
    return "\n".join(
        [line for line in text.splitlines() if line.replace(" ", "").lower() != word]
    )


print(remove_line(text, "othertext"))
```

output:

```
test1
test2
test3
test4
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked fine. I couldn't make it work because I didn't realize that I had to write the argument "othertext" without any space.I wrote "other text" and it was not working. Now it seems obvious reading the remove_line function :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to figure the logic on how you determine why the item is needed to be removed.

**Method-1 Remove third item**

```
input_txt_1 = "test1\ntest2\nothertext\ntest3\ntest4"
input_txt_2 = "test1\ntest2\nOTherTEXT\ntest3\ntest4"
input_txt_3 = "test1\ntest2\nother text\ntest3\ntest4"
input_txt_4 = "test1\ntest2\nOthe rtext\ntest3\ntest4"

def string_split(string):
    return string.split("\n")

splited_text_1 = string_split(input_txt_1)
splited_text_2 = string_split(input_txt_1)
splited_text_3 = string_split(input_txt_1)
splited_text_4 = string_split(input_txt_1)

# Remove third item
splited_text_1.pop(2)
splited_text_2.pop(2)
splited_text_3.pop(2)
splited_text_4.pop(2)

print(splited_text_1)
print(splited_text_2)
print(splited_text_3)
print(splited_text_4)
```

**Method-2 Remove item, that has no 'test' in it**

```
input_txt_1 = "test1\ntest2\nothertext\ntest3\ntest4"
input_txt_2 = "test1\ntest2\nOTherTEXT\ntest3\ntest4"
input_txt_3 = "test1\ntest2\nother text\ntest3\ntest4"
input_txt_4 = "test1\ntest2\nOthe rtext\ntest3\ntest4"

def string_split(string):
    return string.split("\n")

splited_text_1 = string_split(input_txt_1)
splited_text_2 = string_split(input_txt_1)
splited_text_3 = string_split(input_txt_1)
splited_text_4 = string_split(input_txt_1)

filtered_list_1 = [item for item in splited_text_1 if 'test' in item]
filtered_list_2 = [item for item in splited_text_2 if 'test' in item]
filtered_list_3 = [item for item in splited_text_3 if 'test' in item]
filtered_list_4 = [item for item in splited_text_4 if 'test' in item]

print(filtered_list_1)
print(filtered_list_2)
print(filtered_list_3)
print(filtered_list_4)
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems relatively straightforward. You can do this by converting the **othertext** to first lowercase to avoid case-sensitivity. Then split the lines using the new line-character `\n` as the separator. Then iterate through the text and exclude it. The code should be as follows

```
text = """test1
test2
other texT
test3
test4"""

# Convert the target text to lowercase without spaces
target = "othertext".replace(" ", "").lower()

# Split the text into lines
lines = text.split("\n")

new_lines = []

# Iterate and exclude the lines with target text
for line in lines:
    if target not in line.replace(" ", "").lower():
        new_lines.append(line)

# Reconstruct again with new lines
new_text = "\n".join(new_lines)

print(new_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use loop to remove filtered text:

```
for i in (text:=text.split('\n')):
    if i.replace(' ','').lower() == 'othertext':
        text.remove(i)
text = '\n'.join(text)
```

or:

```
for i in (text:=text.split('\n')):
    i.replace(' ','').lower() != 'othertext' or text.remove(i)
text = '\n'.join(text)
```